# Commercial in front of video, HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video

Is it possible to force the user to view a commercial before the actual video begins when using video embedding in HTML5?

Any links to relevant info would be appriciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called [Pre-roll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_advertising).

The HTML5 specification doesn’t. You can write JavaScript and logic around your video in order to create a pre-roll system. Ad servers and ad networks are now starting to support HTML5 video.

To do this I would essentially load the first video and onFinish trigger a method to load up your actual video.

Thanks!